# Input accessory view from one view controller incorrectly appears in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've encountered a bug in my app where the UIToolbar in first view controller appears in the third view controller despite me overriding the input accessory view.

First view controller:

```
class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return toolbar
    }

    ...
```

Second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: BaseViewController {

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    ...
```

Third view controller:

```
class ThirdViewController: BaseViewController {

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    ...
```

I am unsure of what is causing the toolbar to appear in the second view controller. These view controllers are not embedded in a UINavigationController so I don't understand how it can carry over to another screen.

Comment: Seems a little odd - sounds like `FirstViewController` never resigns as responder, so the input accessory view "continues to exist." Maybe put `resignFirstResponder()` in `viewWillDisappear()` in `FirstViewController`?

Comment: @DonMag this did work but I found another case where this doesn't work. When I present another view controller in a UINavigationController the input accessory view from two screens prior appears. This is a very odd situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a difficult problem to solve but I eventually figured out the problem.

So the issue is the method `canBecomeFirstResponder`. If we design our storyboard as follows:

`FirstViewController -(show)-> SecondViewController -(show )-> ThirdViewController`

When we segue to `ThirdViewController`, iOS asks `FirstViewController` if it can become first responder. If `canBecomeFirstResponder` returns true, then the input accessory view of `FirstViewController` will appear in `ThirdViewController`.

The solution is a tad hacky, unfortunately, but it's the only solution I can think of at the moment.

Base view controller:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var shouldBecomeFirstResponder: Bool = false

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return shouldBecomeFirstResponder
    }

    ...
}
```

First view controller:

```
class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        shouldBecomeFirstResponder = true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return toolbar
    }

    @IBAction didTap() {
        shouldBecomeFirstResponder = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSecond", sender: self)
    }
    ...
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        shouldBecomeFirstResponder = false
    }
    ...

    @IBAction didTap() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showThird", sender: self)
    }

    ...
}
```

Third view controller:

```
class ThirdViewController: BaseViewController {

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If @entelect-ca assumption is right - I'd rather check in `FirstViewController` if controller if visible.

Also there is no out-of-the-box way to check if controller is visible (especially when dealing with tabs). So you can add `visible` propery to your view controller:

```
@property BOOL visible;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.visible = true;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.visible = false;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return self.visible;
}
```